# Maintaining two major versions of NPM package

Tags: npm

I have a npm package which is currently lets say version 1.2.2.  I am just about to release version 2. I still want to be able to maintain version 1 alongside version 2 for bug fixes and so on. What would be the best approach to separate code of both versions. @latest will be stored on git master. Where would you store version 1 code? Separate branch, repo? How do people do it in the industry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where would you store version 1 code? Separate branch, repo?

Yes, you should maintain two or more branches.

Master branch could be currently working code so it can be either 2.0.0 version or 1.2.2, but since you haven't released version 2, master branch should contain 1.2.2.

And you can create `2.0.0-dev` branch and work on it.

After you release version 2, you can merge `2.0.0-dev` branch to master branch, and maintain 1.2.2 branch for LTS support and bug fixes.

Also, you can manage [releases](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.13/user/articles/creating-releases) in github, if you're using it.

[image]